# Average number of balls received by each kid

Tags: statistics, word-problem

There are 4 kids A, B, C and D. There are 10 red balls, 20 green balls, and 30 blue balls to distribute among A, B, C and D such that A receives only red and green balls, B receives only green and blue balls, C receives only red and green balls and D receives only red and blue balls. What is the average number of balls received by a kid?

Here is my approach:
A, C and D get 3 red balls on average.
A, B and C get 6 green balls on average.
B and D get 15 blue balls on average.

A gets total of 9 balls
B gets total of 21 balls
C gets total of 9 balls
D gets total of 18 balls

So, each kid gets (9+21+9+18)/4 = 14.25.

If my approach is correct?

Comment: What is the mechanism for distributing the balls?  I don't see how you can do this problem with specifying it.

Comment: If I am interpreting the question correctly... there are $10+20+30=60$ balls total, and four kids total so the average number of balls received by each kid would simply be $\frac{60}{4}=15$.  All of the information about the color of the balls and which kid prefers which colors is completely and totally irrelevant to the question.  As to your attempt, you made some rounding errors.  If each of $A,B,C$ got an average of $6$ greenballs each, that would have meant an average of only $18$ green balls were used... but there are actually $20$ green balls available, not $18$.

Comment: If you were to use *exact* amounts, rather than rounding down for no reason, you would have gotten $A,B,C$ each get an average of $\frac{20}{3}$ green balls each.  Correcting this in your calculations then yields the desired result, but in a tedious and roundabout way that makes invalid assumptions as to how the balls are actually distributed.  Your logic seems to be that you can take the average of the average results for each person individually., but without information as to how the balls are distributed there is not enough information to correctly calculate that.

Comment: @JMoravitz, Got it. Thanks.

Comment: To emphasize the point once more.,  there is a subtle difference in the meanings of the phrases "The average number of balls held by each kid is $15$"  and "The average number of balls held is $15$ for each kid."  We can assert the first one is true, but not the second.  The first implies that if we randomly select a kid and see how many balls they have, the average result would be $15$ (*regardless of how the balls are actually distributed*).  The second phrase implies that the average number of balls held by $A$ is $15$ as well as average held by $B$ is $15$, etc... which need not be true.